# Is there a way to assign record type of opportunity based on lookup field record type

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, process-builder

I am trying to update record type using process and flow. When sales guy selects preferred store(type account but not linked to opportunity account) to opportunity it needs to pick store record type and set it to opportunity record type. To make it easy I named the record types same.

Current Process:
Flow is called everytime preferred store is updated. It passes preferred store and opportunity details to the flow. Store these values in Opportunity 
First I do record lookup on RecordType based on store recordId and get record name(store it in recordName variable). Then I do record lookup again on recordType object and search based on record name and sobjecttype(opportunity) and save it to oppurtunity recordtypeId. Then do a quick update. I activated flow and process but for some reason it is not changing.

Comment: Your logic is fine.  I have a feeling its something minor.  Have you checked the Variable's Input/Output type to make sure its being passed through and isnt Private?  Want to get on a quick screen-share so we can walk-through it together?

Comment: Also - are you using the correct value for the Name in both RecordType searches?  The DeveloperName and Label are two different things, and that might be causing the issue.  This all comes back to probably throwing a 'screen' in with text of the variables outputted for you after each step.  Launch this from a button.  Just make sure the correct values are being populated as you go down each step.

Comment: @DavidLitton I tried setting the screens and trigger with a button. Is says I have a unhanded exception. Now I am not sure what is wrong. I checked variable types too. I would love to share my screen